# Deleted Contents Restores Automatically In Database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a promoters page in one of my website showing their image, name and event details. When I delete promoters contents from the database,The content deleted succesfully. But after a particular time same contents restores automatically to database.I dont know how this restore process happens after deleteing the same content from the database.

My Query is

```
$query="delete from tbl_promoters where id=$userId"; mysql_query($query) or die($query);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't know I'm sure we're not going to be able to work it out from what you've posted here.

Comment: When you use sql query `delete from tablename where something=1` it won't come back as far as i know.

Comment: please display your query and code if any then

Comment: $query="delete from tbl_promoters where id=$userId";
mysql_query($query) or die($query);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query="delete from tbl_promoters where id=$userId";
mysql_query($query) or die("Sorry there might be some probloem");
```

instead of using `or die($query)` use something else as die will not fire your query if any problem is there.